# How can I configure FileZilla to first try the provided password before trying private keys?

Tags: windows, ssh, filezilla, pageant

I use FileZilla 3.29.0 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Amongst the SFTP servers, I connect to, some of them use password authentication, and others use private keys. I use Pageant to manage the private keys.

When connecting to an SFTP server that uses password authentication, how can I configure FileZilla to first try the provided password before trying private keys?

The motivation is that some SFTP servers have a limit on how many passwords or private keys can be tried when attempting to authenticate. Since by default FileZilla first tries all private keys loaded in Pageant, it sometimes hits this limit before trying the provided password. I don't want to have to close Pageant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileZilla does not have such configuration option.

You would have to use another SFTP client that supports this.

For example, *my* WinSCP has session option [*Attempt authentication using Pageant*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication). The same option as PuTTY SSH client has. Both WinSCP and FileZilla use PuTTY code to implement SSH, but FileZilla does not expose this option.

Comment: Thanks, I actually use WinSCP pretty much daily, and it indeed supports this :)